# How to deal with python dictionary assignment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am currently struggling to solve this issue. Need help.
What I am trying to achieve is the answer: below:(expected answer)

```
{'and': 1.91629073, 'document': 1.22314355, 'first': 1.51082562, 'is': 1., 'one': 1.91629073, 'second': 1.91629073, 'the': 1., 'third': 1.91629073, 'this,: 1.}        ]
```

But what I am actually getting is this:

```
{'and': 2.791759469228055, 'document': 3.0794415416798357, 'first': 2.9459101490553135, 'is': 3.1972245773362196, 'one': 2.791759469228055, 'second': 2.791759469228055, 'the': 3.1972245773362196, 'third': 2.791759469228055, 'this': 3.1972245773362196}
```

Main point of consideration is this code: The code and formula is right, but for some reason its taking
in few extra numerical values in in len(corpus)

```
vocab1[word2] = 1+(math.log(1+len(corpus)/1+count))
```

The actual code starts from here:

```
corpus = [
 'this is the first document',
 'this document is the second document',
 'and this is the third one',
 'is this the first document',]

import math
unique_words = set() # at first we will initialize an empty set
lenofcorpus= len(corpus)
# print(lenofcorpus)
vocab1 = dict()
# vocab = dict()
# check if its list type or not
if isinstance(corpus, (list,)):
    for row in corpus: # for each review in the dataset
        for word in row.split(" "): # for each word in the review. #split method converts a string into list of words
            if len(word) < 2:
                continue
            unique_words.add(word)
    unique_words = sorted(list(unique_words))
    # print(unique_words)
    for idx, word2 in enumerate(unique_words) :
      count = 0
      for sentence in corpus :
        if word2 in sentence :
          count+=1
      # print(word2, count)
          vocab1[word2] = count
          # print(lenofcorpus)
          vocab1[word2] = 1+(math.log(1+len(corpus)/1+count))#its taking log of 12/2 instead it should take 5/2, its taking 7 extra or six
    print(vocab1)
```

I want to know how to achieve the desired answer. Secondly, what was the thought process to arrive at that answer, and what I am doing wrong. It would really help if anyone gives an explanation. I know I am also doing something wrong with dictionary looping function and also assignment.
FYI: len(corpus) = 4 # thats the length of entire corpus, it has 4 sentences.

Comment: len(corpus) is 4, I don't know where you get some 'extra numerical value' here

Comment: vocab1[word2] = 1+(math.log(1+len(corpus)/1+count)) Its here where the code is failing. The desired answer should be something else, but for some reason the answer which I am receiving is something else.

Comment: Maybe you meant 1+(math.log(1+len(corpus)/(1+count))) instead?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: might as well shorten your unique words:`unique_words = sorted(set( w for s in corpus for w in s.split() if len(w)>1))`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing parentheses.  The results you describe you want correspond to this:

```
vocab1[word2] = 1+(math.log((1+len(corpus))/(1+count)))
```

or spelled out:

```
numerator = (1+len(corpus))
denominator = (1+count)
result = 1+math.log(numerator/denominator)
```

What you had orginally written is equivalent to

```
vocab1[word2] = 1+math.log(1+(len(corpus)/1)+count)
```

it's a pretty common mistake to write `x/y+z` when you meant `x/(y+z)`, or `x+y/z` when you meant `(x+y)/z`, you've manage to do both at the same time.

Comment: You guys are fantastic. Thanks for the logic and tutorial. Still learning to create clean codes. Cant thank enough. Godbless